# Virtual Range object in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I have a macro that I am trying to use to crawl through a Workbook looking for instances of a specific User-Defined Function (UDF), and checking whether a criterion is met for the arguments to each UDF that it finds.

The fundamental issue is how to take a Range object (single cell) and resolve the arguments to a UDF to actual values i.e. not simply read the .Formula string, which may contain a mixture of actual values and cell references, but to recognise the arguments that are actually cell references and resolve those. If I were doing this manually, it would be a bit like selecting each argument to the UDF and hitting F9 to calculate, if that makes sense?

I am open to any robust ways to achieve the end goal, which as I said, is to be able to resolve the actual values of the arguments passed to a UDF, obviously not from within the UDF code itself.

To be specific, I am looping through all worksheets in the Workbook using:

```
For Each ws in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
```

I am then using a search function (outside of the scope of this issue) to return a collection of cells that are using my UDF, which I will call

```
UDF(arg1, arg2)
```

for the purposes of keeping it simple.

I then iterate through that collection of cells, and for each one, I would like to essentially concatenate the arguments into a ""-delimited string. So, if a particular cell contains the formula

```
=UDF(A1, "test")
```

Let's say cell A1 contains "January", to be clear, I do not want "A1\test" to be returned, but "January\test".

Comment: Nothing related to what you try accomplishing is clear. At least, for me... Please, try an example, better explaining what you try doing, which to be the input and what such a pseudo procedure should return. Like I said, don't be so abstract, since only you understand what is to be done. Use examples, please...

Comment: I will just note that you cannot create a virtual range. They exist only as cells on worksheets.

Comment: Thanks @Rory, I suspect that answers my question. I will clarify my question with some more specific detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since revised my complicated (but mostly functional) answer above, to a much more simple form making use of Worksheet.Evaluate:

```
Private Function resolveCellRef(CellRef As String, cell As Range) As String
    ' This function takes an argument to a UDF that might be a cell reference or Named Range, and tries to resolve the value.
    ' It needs to handle the cases where a value has been passed, and just return the value again.
    ' RMB v1.0.0: whole overhaul of how this function works
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = cell.Parent
    resolveCellRef = ws.Evaluate(CellRef)
    
End Function
```

Kind of a 'well duh' moment when I realised this Worksheet method existed!
I spent considerably more effort making the argument parser work robustly, and this is actually quite straight forward, as using the worksheet version of Evaluate (instead of the Application method of the same name) automatically inherits context for cell references, Named Ranges etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have solved this (there may be other, more elegant ways).
I ended up writing a helper function to attempt to resolve a cell reference (same sheet, different sheet, Named Range) and used that (along with special-character trimming) to resolve all the arguments to my UDF. Essentially it's a parser.

The code is (for the argument resolver - assuming one has already parsed the UDF .Formula string to extract the arguments using Split on commas or whatever):

```
Private Function resolveCellRef(cellRef As String, cell As Range) As String
    ' This function takes an argument to a UDF that might be a cell reference or Named Range, and tries to resolve the value.
    ' It needs to handle the cases where a value has been passed, and just return the value again.
    ' Created by Rob Baker, 11/02/2022
    Dim pos1 As Integer, tmpStr As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim error_raised As Boolean
    
    ' Check if it is already a string argument. If so, trim the quotation marks and return
    If Left(cellRef, 1) = """" Then
        resolveCellRef = Replace(cellRef, """", vbNullString)
        Exit Function
    End If
    ' Check for whether the argument is a cell reference to a foreign sheet
    error_raised = False
    pos1 = InStr(1, cellRef, "!")
    Select Case pos1
    Case 0
        Set ws = cell.Parent                            ' Cell reference must be local to sheet
        tmpStr = cellRef
    Case Else
        tmpStr = Left(cellRef, pos1 - 1)
        If Left(tmpStr, 1) = "'" Then                   ' Trim apostrophes if present
            tmpStr = Left(tmpStr, Len(tmpStr) - 1)
            tmpStr = Right(tmpStr, Len(tmpStr) - 1)
        End If
        Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(tmpStr)      ' Set the ws reference
        tmpStr = Right(cellRef, Len(cellRef) - pos1)    ' This is now the cell reference alone
    End Select
    On Error GoTo errhandler                            ' Use error handling to handle two known issues
    resolveCellRef = ws.Range(tmpStr).Value2
    If error_raised Then resolveCellRef = ActiveWorkbook.Names(cellRef).RefersToRange.Value2
    Exit Function
    
errhandler:
    If Err.Number = 1004 And Not error_raised Then      ' Set the error_raised flag and resume next to try a Named Range
        Err.Clear: error_raised = True
        Resume Next
    ElseIf Err.Number = 1004 And error_raised Then      ' If we get here, then the cellRef isn't a cell reference or Named Range, so just return it as is
        Err.Clear
        resolveCellRef = cellRef
        Resume Next
    End If
End Function
```